# zxing.net: iOS not recognizing any barcodes

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, zxing.net

I'm using this library for my Xamarin.Forms app: https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile

Just to start off, it's working perfectly on Android. iOS shows the camera viewfinder, but it doesn't ever recognize any barcodes.

I initialize it in my AppDelegate as required:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();

    ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.iOS.Platform.Init();
    LoadApplication(new App(new iOSInitializer()));

    return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
}
```

I also set the permission description in Info.plist:

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Please allow access to the camera to scan barcodes</string>
```

But I guess that's obvious, or else the camera viewfinder wouldn't work either.

Comment: There is an open issue for this, you can try what stavroaudio has found: https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/issues/895

Comment: Except his issue is different. He had a crash in his code after retrieving the barcode.

Comment: cissemy has reported the issue and he doesn't say that it's crashing. I guess they have some issues probably. Try downgrading to a previous version

Answer (score 0):

I got some issues with Zxing in my app too, but i noticed that some problems are solved with the right version in both Android and IOS, i'm currently using the version 2.3.1 (not 2.4.1) and works perfect, besides, i realized that you should not use your ZxingPage first at the [stack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/), that is why i always put a page before to avoid any crash:

```
 var root = Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack[0];
            Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.InsertPageBefore(new View(), root);
```

And then i call the ZxingPage. Hope it helps :)